# Overlapping rectangles (Java)

Tags: java

Can you pls explain the logic behind the way this code finds out if two rectangles overlap?

```
public static boolean overlaps(GRectangle r1, GRectangle r2) {
    return (r1.getX() < r2.getX() + r2.getWidth())
        && (r1.getX() + r1.getWidth() > r2.getX())
        && (r1.getY() < r2.getY() + r2.getHeight())
        && (r1.getY() + r1.getHeight() > r2.getY());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For two rectangles to overlap, they must overlap in both horizontally and vertically. The first two conditions test for horizontal overlap and the second two test for vertical overlap.

To test for overlap of the extents in a single dimension, you need to consider the possible ways that the rectangles could *not* overlap. One possibility is that the left edge of the first rectangle is to the right of the right edge of the second rectangle, so that there is a space between them. The second possibility is just the vice versa: that the right edge of the first rectangle is two the left of the second rectangle. If both of theses possibilities are false then there must be an overlap, so the if statement tests for the opposite of both of these conditions.

Because less than/greater than and not less than or equals/greater than or equals are used, then rectangles that touch but do not overlap will not be considered overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

The first condition checks to make sure that the left side of `r1` is not to the right of the right side of `r2`. If this was the case then the rectangles could obviously not overlap.

The other conditions check similar things:

Condition 2 makes sure the right side of `r1` is to the right of the left side of `r2`.

Condition 3 makes sure the bottom side `r1` is below the top of `r2`.

Condition 4 makes sure the top of `r1` is above the bottom of `r2`.

If any of these conditions fail there is no way for the rectangles to overlap. They overlap excatly when all of the conditions are `true`.

*Sidenote: I assume the coordinate system to have (0,0) at the lower left corner. The same basic logic is true for any other orientation or inversion of the coordinate system as well.*